# Best method to store a complete DNA sequence in hadoop ecosystem

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, dna-sequence

My name is Lokesh and i have to make a dna database and analysis tool using hadoop. Can anyone kindly tell me, what method should be used to store complete DNA sequences ( 3 billion base pairs approx.) in hadoop ecosystem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a opinionated question, and is likely to be closed :( just FYI

Comment: Indeed.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask